Constant in the Banach valued Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund inequality
Let $(\xi_i)_{i=1}^n$ be a sequence of real-valued independent random variables with zero mean. The classical Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund inequality is the following
\begin{align}
(E(\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i)^p)^{1/p}\le C_p (E(\sum_{i=1}^n|\xi_i|^2)^{p/2})^{1/p}. 
\end{align}
The constant $C_p\sim p$ is well-known. My question is what about the Banach valued version. More precisely, for any UMD space $B$ with the norm $\|\cdot\|_B$ and $(\xi_i)_{i=1}^n$ be a sequence of $B$-valued independent random variables with zero mean, the following Banach valued Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund inequality holds:
\begin{align}
(E\|\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i\|_B^p)^{1/p}\le C_p (E\|\sum_{i=1}^n|\xi_i|^2\|_B^{p/2})^{1/p}. 
\end{align}
I couldn't find a good reference to tell us what the $C_p$ is. Does $C_p\sim p$ still hold?
